# Json Object send to save service return error " You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected."

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Trying to create  a custom object to send to server.

```
 get f() { return this.userForm.controls; }

var patientInfo = {
        "createdBy": loginId,
        "patientId": 34,
        "careGiverName": this.f.name.value,
        "careGiverTel":  this.f.tel.value,
        "cateGiverMob":  this.f.mobile.value,
       
      };
```

creating  a new object, custom key name. There are other "key" that need to be added. Time being added one "userInfo".

```
 var saveData : any = {};
 saveData.userInfo = userInfo;
```

Invoke service

```
this.http.post(environment.api+'/api/user/save', saveData);
```

Throws exception at this line.

It throws console error.

```
 You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an **Observable**, **Promise**, **Array**, or **Iterable**.
```

Comment: where is the error in you code?

Comment: It's difficult to know what's wrong with the information provided. It sounds like the backend expects a file stream and you give it json.

Comment: Service tested passing json using postman. works fine.

Comment: search for `switchMap` or simillar rxjs operators in your code

Comment: instead of saveData variable at calling of service, try to pass patientInfo variable because this is a valid object and BE was expecting an object like this maybe.

Comment: @user630209: The error most probably has not to do with what you send to the server, but how the HTTP call is triggered in the front-end. Please show more code on how the request is called and what other RxJS operators you're using.